# How to control background execution of Apps Script Custom Functions?

Tags: google-apps-script

The list of the Apps Script add-on executions shows that the custom functions are executed in the background every 20 minutes. How to control/avoid executions of custom functions in the background? The background executions of custom functions is a waste of resources. I would like to control the execution of my custom functions.

Answer (score 0):

#### Check out [Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

[image]

I'm not sure what kind of triggers you have installed, but it sounds like a [time-based trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers).

If you go into the menu pictured above, you will be able to manage any triggers you have installed. Including changing the time period of your 20 minute one.

#### [Quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)

One execution every 20 minutes is not something to worry about in terms of quotas, as you have the ability to run many many more executions. Though of course, if running it every 20 minutes is useless to you, by all means, change the period or delete it!

Comment: I have absolutely no triggers. However they run in the background without my control.

Comment: @user494611  Can you share a screen shot of your executions page? Maybe that has some clues as to where these executions are coming from? You mention Add-ons, can you say which add-on it is?

Comment: The log is not descriptive enough for investigation. Only Google engineers has access to the descriptive log for such executions.

Comment: In script.google.com there is an executions page where you can see all the executions, does nothing appear there? Also, what is the add-on? You say its not descriptive enough, but can you share anyway, what does it say?